# Determining Values of Parameters so that Observation Equation is Stationary

Tags: time-series, self-study, variance, covariance

> Consider a system process given by $x_t=-0.9x_{t-2}+z_t$,$t=1,2,…,n$ with observation $y_t=x_t+v_t$  where ${z_t}$ and ${v_t}$ are independent white noise with variances $σ^2$ and $σ_v^2$.
> Assume that $x_0\sim \mathcal N(0,σ_0^2)$ and $x_{-1}\sim \mathcal N(0,σ_1^2)$, and that $x_0$ and $x_{-1}$ are independent. Find the values of $\sigma_0^2$ and $\sigma_1^2$ that make the observations, $y_t$, stationary.

So for $y_t$ to be stationary, it must have a constant mean and autocovariance function independent of time. The mean is obviously zero, since $x_t$ must have mean zero since it's an $AR(2)$ process, and $v_t$ has mean zero.

The autocovariance function is a sum of the autocovariance of the $AR(2)$ process $x_t$ and $v_t$. For $t=1$ we obtain $\gamma_y(0) =  cov(-0.9x_{-1} + z_1,-0.9x_{-1} + z_1) = 0.9^2 \sigma_1^2 + \sigma^2$. Similarly, for $t=2$ we get $\gamma_y(0) = 0.9^2 \sigma_0^2 + \sigma^2$. In the general case, the autocovariance is $$ \gamma_y(0) = \frac{\sigma^2}{1 - (-0.9)^2} + \sigma_v^2$$ for $t \neq 1,2$ and $\gamma_y(2k) = (-0.9)^k \big(\gamma_y(0) - \sigma^2_v \big) + \sigma^2_v$ for $k = 1,2,...$ and $\gamma_y = 0$ otherwise.

$\gamma_y(0)$ can clearly be made stationary by choosing the correct values of $\sigma_0^2$ and $\sigma_1^2$. However $\gamma_y(2k)$ is not stationary regardless of the choice of $\sigma_1^2$ and $\sigma_0^2$.

Any help?

Comment: Solving this exercise will reveal the relevance of those variances.  What, then, is your solution?

Comment: I made an edit. My findings so far suggest that the autocovariance is not stationary for $\gamma_y(2k)$ for $k = 1,2,...$ regardless of the values of $\sigma_0^2$ and $\sigma_1^2$.

Comment: A time series can be stationary, but individual terms cannot.  What, then, do you mean by saying "$\gamma_y(2k)$" is not stationary??

Comment: @whuber Let me rephrase. The autocovariance for $t = 2k, \gamma_y(2k), k = 1,...$ is dependent on time $t$, meaning the time series $y_t$ is not stationary. And this dependence is not a function of $\sigma_0^2$ or $\sigma_1^2$. Therefore, I fail to see how I can choose the parameters $\sigma^2_0$ and $\sigma_1^2$ to make $y_t$ stationary.

Comment: I do not follow your notation.  I would expect the covariances to refer to *times* and *lags,* but you refer to what looks like a lag $2k$ as a "time."  It's fine for the covariances to change with lag in a stationary process.  You need to check whether they change with time or not.